# Creating a list of TextView's in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a list of TextView's in my Android app of name's and organizations.  However, the whole list is the same, for example:

```
Joe's work for Construction Co.
15hrs of 60hrs
Joe's work for Construction Co.
15hrs of 60hrs
Joe's work for Construction Co.
15hrs of 60hrs
...
```

is repeated five times in the list in the app. Here is the relevant code:

```
class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Long> {
private ArrayList<Long> items;
private FakeIDO ido;

public IconicAdapter(Context context,int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Long> ids, FakeIDO ido){
    super(WorkList.this, R.layout.feed_list, ids);
    this.items = ids;
    this.ido = ido;
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    }
    for(long id : items){ 
        TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
        TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
        if (tt != null) {
              tt.setText(ido.getName(id) + "'s work for " + ido.getOrganization(id));
        }
        if(bt != null){
              bt.setText( ido.totalWorked(id) + "hrs of " + ido.estimatedHours(id) + "hrs");
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```

Here is the xml view this class is working off of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toptext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, I understand that the same instance is being returned when I call "TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);", but I don't know what to change to get a new instance object each time. What am I missing?

Comment: `getView()` is called once for each individual list item, and you are iterating through your entire `items` ArrayList every time.  I assume that 'Joe' is the last item in the list, so his information is displayed for every list item.  You should only set the text of the text views once in each `getView()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use your `getView` like this

```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    }

        TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
        TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
        // get the 'id' for position.
        int id = items.get(position);
        if (tt != null) {
              tt.setText(ido.getName(id) + "'s work for " + ido.getOrganization(id));
        }
        if(bt != null){
              bt.setText( ido.totalWorked(id) + "hrs of " + ido.estimatedHours(id) + "hrs");
        }

    return v;
}
```

Comment: yea, looks like I misunderstood how the getView function is called by Android.

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing

```
TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
```

to

```
TextView tt = new TextView(this);
CharSequence text = ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.toptext)).getText();
tt.setText(text);
```

This will instantiate a new TextView with the same contents, which I think is what you're saying the underlying problem is.

Hope that helps!