# How to make a list of textviews?

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

Basically here is a mspaint demonstraiton of what I want to accomplish:

[image]

I do not want the outline to be visible to the user, it was just to give you an idea of what I want to do. I want new textviews to take position under each other whenever a new goal is added from the edittext-button combo on the bottom part of the GUI.

I know how to save the data - SQLite. But I have no idea how to make new textviews be on the bottom of the last one - and if there is no more room on the screen I want that textview part to be scrollable.

I don't know what I need to use to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use a listview for this purpose

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662112/creating-a-list-of-textviews-in-android

Answer (score 1):

create two xml files.
One consisting of list view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/bkgrnd_320x285">

<ListView
        android:id="@+id/List1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and another xml for just the textView eg. row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
 >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Display Name"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in the main activity u need to refer to both the xml files as follows

> ListView ll = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List1);
>
> ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.row,R.id.textView2, arraylist_you_want_to_display);
>
> ll.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

where **R.layout.row** is the row.xml consisting of textView

And **R.id.textView2** is the id of the textView present in the row.xml

Answer (score 0):

You may create a LinearLayout, setting the orientation to vertical.

Adding a ScrollView or ListView to show the upper part, with android:weight=1

Add the EditText to the LinearLayout, and this is done.

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/List1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weight="1"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```